# SharePoint 2016 cannot instance SecureStoreProvider

Tags: authentication, sharepoint-on-prem

I upgraded from SP 2013 to SP 2016. Now I have got an APP that reads data from the SecureStore. For that, the first step is the following for 2013:

```
ISecureStoreProvider provider = SecureStoreProviderFactory.Create();
```

I have got the following imports:

```
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.BusinessData.Infrastructure.SecureStore;
using Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreService.Server;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
```

Now the compiler says the class does not exist. Did anyone already tried to connect to SecureStore in SharePoint 2016?

Comment: I can confirm the class is still there and marked as `public static` in `Microsoft.Office.SecureStoreservice`. I take it you updated your assembly references to v16?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... found the problem.
I referenced the wrong assembly of the SecureStoreService. I had to reference directly from GAC. So you can't trust the VS assembly selector...

Thanks for your replies!